# Why are my villagers not using my Storage Barn?

Tags: banished

I have a small village consisting of just a few houses, a storage barn, a stockpile, a 100% full storage cart, a blacksmith and a woodcutter in the centre, and a gatherer, a forester, a hunter, a herbalist and a couple of houses in the nearby forest.

For some reason, my villagers are barely my storage barn.  They are leaving their food in baskets on the road outside the barn, despite the barn being only 12% full.  Does anyone have any ideas as to why this is?

Comment: How long has the barn been completed and the food outside been going on? Also, how many laborers do you have?

Comment: The barn had been completed a long time, I had a couple of labourers.  Eventually (over a long period) the storage barn did get used and the food outside slowly disappeared - but it was an odd little quirk.  Maybe the lack of labourers was the issue.

Comment: My guess is that at the time when the laborers started to carry the items back, there was no room, and once there was room the goods outside went away. But that is pure speculation

Comment: One possibility is to 'tell' the laborers to collect such forgotten food baskets with the priority tool (F2 menu, item 6). Try to mark such baskets with this tool. This seems to work for not yet collected resources at mines too.

Comment: Aha, I did not know you could use the priority tool on baskets.  Thank you, @PeterCo.